# Como recorrer una funcion postgrest

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

necesito de su ayuda, tengo una función en postgrest que me funciona, pero necesito realizarle una modificación, pero no se como hacer el recorrido y me muestre todo los resultados y no solo el primero, mi código es el siguiente, en mis argumentos recibo xarea" integer, "xsa" integer

```
DECLARE
    res rowtype_hora;
    tiempo RECORD;
    plazo RECORD;
    xhr integer;
BEGIN

   select horario_id into xhr from view_proceso where id_area = xarea;

    FOR tiempo IN select id,codigo,inicio,termino 
                    from cronometro 
                    where hr = xhr and tipo = 8
    LOOP
        res:=null;
        res.id_hora := tiempo.id;
        res.inicio := tiempo.inicio;
        res.termino := tiempo.termino; 

        FOR plazo IN select * 
                    from hora 
                    where area_id = xarea and subarea = xsa and hora_id = tiempo.id  and solicitud_id = 18
                    order by jornada
        LOOP
            
            if plazo.jornada = 1 then
                   select nombre into res.lunes from programa where id = plazo.programa_id;
                elseif plazo.jornada = 2 then
                   select nombre into res.martes from programa where id = plazo.programa_id;
                elseif plazo.jornada = 3 then
                   select nombre into res.miercoles from programa where id = plazo.programa_id;
                elseif plazo.jornada = 4 then
                   select nombre into res.jueves from programa where id = plazo.programa_id;
                elseif plazo.jornada = 5 then
                   select nombre into res.viernes from programa where id = plazo.programa_id;
            end if;
        END LOOP;
        if res.lunes is not null or res.martes is not null or res.miercoles is not null or res.jueves is not null
         or res.viernes is not null then
            return next res;
        end if;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Si ejecuto la función la base me trae la siguiente información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que necesito lograr es esto, en donde el día lunes por ejemplo me muestra 2 áreas.  Esta condición se cumple si mi xarea>50, sino, solamente me debe mostrar una área.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Tabla Hora
id: Integer
area_id: Integer
jornada: integer
subarea_id: Integer
hora_id: integer
solicitud_id: Integer

Tabla Programa
id: Integer
nombre: character varying
sigla: character varying
```

Cómo puedo recorrer la función para que me permita realizar lo que necesito?

Comment: tienes la misma tabla para el resultado actual y para el deseado. Y como recomendación, es necesario ver sobre qué tablas se traen los datos: incluye la **definición** de las tablas, preferiblemente **como texto** para no tener que replicar tu ejemplo desde una imagen

Comment: @Alfabravo, he actualizado mi código, no se si era esa información la que me solicitabas. Gracias